# iPhone Configuration Profiles - Creating / Modifying

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, configuration-profiles

My university has a 'configuration profile' to allow us to connect to the campus secure WiFi - which is great, save for that it forces us to have a passcode (which I neither like nor want). The profile is outdated, as the network now has it's own security on top of the connection, and so it's objective (to stop unauthorised people using the network) is moot.

Is there any way to modify the configuration profile / read it's contents and write my own (it's unsigned anyway) to replace it?

Answer (score 1):

The configuration profiles are normal XML files, you can modify them with any text editor. Also, there is an [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465) to create new profiles. On the [iPhone Support Enterprise](http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/) site you can get more information about it. Just e-mail the modified config file to your device and install it.

I checked the mobileconfig from my last University and there seems to be no explicit setting to allow people to save their passwords, to I guess there is one to deny it.

Comment: Wonderful. I'll give that a blast and let you know how it turns out.

Comment: But you need the file though. If you just have the installed profile, you probably won't be able to export that for modification: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/257742/373466