# Apple Profiles - Apple Configurator 2

Tags: apple-configurator

I've been looking for hours now on how to edit a profile on Apple Configurator but to no luck. There are some similar responses, but none of them were of too much help. I am trying to edit a profile that *exists on a iPad Air*, but not the mac. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to edit a profile whilst only having the profile on a device. You must have the profile on your computer to edit it. Profiles can't be exported from a device to be edited in Configurator.